# Getting "Error in ets() while using Forecast function" in RStudio code

Tags: r, forecast

```
# ---
setwd("F:/Business Analytics/PowerBi/Data")
library(forecast)
SF <- read.csv("test.csv",stringsAsFactors = F,header=T)
ds1 = data.frame(SF$Year, SF$Jan, SF$Feb, SF$Mar, SF$Apr, SF$May, SF$Jun, SF$Jul, SF$Aug, SF$Sep, SF$Oct, SF$Nov, SF$Dec)

forecast(ds1)
# ---
```

When I run above code in RStudio to generate Forecast Line Graph using CSV data, I get following error:
Error in ets(object, lambda = lambda, biasadj = biasadj, allow.multiplicative.trend = allow.multiplicative.trend,  :
y should be a univariate time series

Can someone please tell me what am I missing in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that while your data looks like a timeseries object at first glance, after reading from csv it in fact is just a `data.frame`. Therefore the `forecast::ets()` thinks you are supplying a multivariate timeseries it reads the multiple data.frame columns.

Possibly there is a better read function that I am not aware of... my approach would be the following:

```
# sample data
SF <- data.table::fread("Year   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2021    1   2   3   4   5   3   1   2   3   4   5   3
2022    1   2   3   4   5   3   1   2   3   4   5   3")

library(tidyverse) # you could just call dplyr
# make columns to rows
myDf <- tidyr::pivot_longer(SF, -Year, names_to = "Month", values_to = "Vals") %>%
    # get sequential month number to be able guarantee order 
    dplyr::mutate(Month = match(Month, base::month.abb)) %>%
    # arrange data (just to be sure)
    dplyr::arrange(Year, Month)

# build time series with frequency and starting point (we can do this as we guaranteed the correct order in the prior dplyr pipe
ts(myDf$Vals, frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)) %>% 
    forecast::ets()
```

If you want to dive a bit deeper into forecasting timeseries in R there is an excelent openbook from the author of the `forecast` package you are using: https://otexts.com/fpp2/